# Yii2: login as their own child role

Tags: php, authentication, yii, yii2, rbac

I have created `Yii2 app`.
There are three roles in my app.
`1. admin`
`2. client`
`3. user`

Now the `user` is child of `client` and `client` is child of `admin`.
so `admin` is parent of bother role i.e. `client and user`.

Now i have an interface for `user-management` from admin can see all users.
Now if `admin` want to login in any users account then he can login directly with knowing his `password`.
So how can I achieve this using `yii2` or `php`.

Or I want to add somthing like if admin want to access his child panel then how he can access?

Please help.
Thank You.

Comment: if he already is logged in as admin then how can he re login as user or any other?

Comment: so i want to add somthing like if admin want to access his child panel then how he can access?

Comment: I personally would add the option on the admin panel to switch to another user's panel by selecting him/her from a list of all the users. You just need to check for the admin role and show those options.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

- Use RBAC for user authentication
- Create separate controller and action for child data and other
  functionalities
- Check if user is admin then enable access for those controller
  actions using RBAC

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to use RBAC in yii2.

- Setup your Rbac tables as in in the link [Yii2 Rbac](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac)
- You can either use db/file based. Maintaining your relations in DB would be better.
- Once you have your tables setup as in the link you need to setup relations in the table.
- You have auth_item, auth_item_child, auth_assignment and auth_rule child.
- I don't use auth_rule as I predefine my action roles in the controller.
- First create the roles in auth_item
- In your case it will be admin, client and user.
- Next in the auth_item_child you have parent child columns.
- Your parent will be admin and child for same will be the client.
- Next parent is client and the child for this will be the user.
- Now a client has access to everything that the user has.
- And admin can have access to whatever the client has access to.
  [image]
- If you see the image here the user can only ride the bike, but the client can ride bike and drive car as well, whereas the admin can ride bike, drive car and drive bus as well.
- Once the relations are setup you can assign user_id's to the roles in auth_assignment table.

**Application**

- Once your setup is done, now in your controller you can roles and action.

  public function behaviors()
  {

  ```
  return [
      'access' => [
          'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
          'rules' => [

              [
                  'allow' => true,
                  'roles' => ['Admin'],
                  'actions' => ['index','create','update','view','delete','driveBus'],
              ],

               [
                  'allow' => true,
                  'roles' => ['client'],
                  'actions' => ['driveCar'],
              ]
                 [
                  'allow' => true,
                  'roles' => ['user'],
                  'actions' => ['rideBike'],
              ]

          ],
      ],
  ];
  ```

  }
- Now you have your behaviors set.As admin you can login and access everything and others will have access to what actions thay have been assigned to.
- Now you can have a login as client or user option.
- You can set it up as if logged in user is an admin, he can use the login as option.
- Create a method where it checks for if the user is admin or not.Something like the below pasted code.

  ```
    $auth = AuthAssignment::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity>user_id])->one();
      if($auth->item_name == 'Admin'){
          //Get the user email and password here and apply login method here.
          //Now you will be signed in with that user session
      }
  ```